# Builtin func "append" in method for pointer receiver

Tags: pointers, go, append, slice

Having two types:

```
type Headers []HeaderItem

type HeaderItem struct { // This one doesn't really matter. Could be any other type
  Name  string
  Value string
}
```

I would like to add a function with the slice as receiver. How can I do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
func (h *Headers) AddHeaderItem(item HeaderItem) {
    h = &(append( *h, item ))
}
```

The compiler complains about it, so this doesn't work.

I tried:

```
func (h Headers) AddHeaderItem(item HeaderItem) {
    h = append( h, item )
}
```

This actually compiles but doesn't do what I want: when later on `range`ing over the items, I get an empty result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `AddHeaderItem()` method `h` is a pointer. You do not want to change the pointer but the pointed value:

```
func (h *Headers) AddHeaderItem(item HeaderItem) {
    *h = append(*h, item)
}
```

Testing it:

```
h := Headers{}
fmt.Println(h)
h.AddHeaderItem(HeaderItem{"myname1", "myvalue1"})
fmt.Println(h)
h.AddHeaderItem(HeaderItem{"myname2", "myvalue2"})
fmt.Println(h)
```

Output:

```
[]
[{myname1 myvalue1}]
[{myname1 myvalue1} {myname2 myvalue2}]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4bGt-vGDq0).

Comment: yess, this works. Must have had a type when I was trying this. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Don't do this. Don't try too be too clever. Just use a struct with the slice as a member. It adds literally zero overhead, and whoever will have to look at your code later (including you) will be grateful.

Comment: Well I'm not trying to be too clever. I'm just following the guide which encourages me to attach a function to virtually anything. Why shouldn't this work? My goal was to use this type as a composite for another struct later on.

Comment: Creating a type in this manner isn't being "clever", and in fact it's the entire basis for the `sort` package.